# Microsoft Access report generating data from other dates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I am trying to show data from the start of the year until the month the user enter in the Microsoft Access and everything works perfectly, however when I enter month 5 for example it shows the correct data but it also shows data for months 10, 11, 12. and if I enter month between 10-12 it only shows me data from months 10-12 and not from 1-9. Is there any way possible what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have the month values as *text*: "5", "10", "11", etc., not as *numbers*: 5, 10, 11.

Correct that, and it will work:

```
MonthNumer <= Val([Enter Month])
```

Or, if this is in a query, define the data type of the parameter as Integer:

```
Parameters [Enter Month] Integer;
Select ....
```

Comment: Actually I have the date and I am extracting it by Month([Renew]) function and comparing it to <= [Enter Month] and it gives me correct result but it also gives result of the months of 10, 11, 12.   Also if it do <= Month(Date()) it seems to produce correct results

Comment: Yes, `[Enter Month]` is most likely text. See edited answer, please.